# EmberJS: how to split rendering of the DOM?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to optimise the rendering in my app. I have the following loop:

```
stuff.forEach(function(content){
    ...
    content.doUpdates(); // Generates a bunch of DOM updates
})
```

If `stuff` has only 2 or 3 elements it is all fine, but when it has 10 or more, rendering starts to lock the browser - and it is normal since it tries to do all the updates at once.

So I would like to split the rendering. My initial thought was to put each `doUpdates` in a `Ember.run.next` http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_next (I don't mind if each content is rendered separately). But "multiple operations scheduled with Ember.run.next will coalesce into the same later run loop".

Is there a recommended way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`Ember.run.next` is really just a fancy `setInterval`. There isn't much benefit unless you are looking for a quick fix.

`Ember.run.scheduleOnce` is a better alternative. You can give it the specific lifecycle runloop like `afterRender`, depending on when you you want it to run within the runloop.

One approach that I have found useful is to make sure the bound properties are updated in a phased manner. This gives some low handing fruit in terms of performance, as you are really just letting ember take care of most of the work.

Another simple way to gain a performance boost is to not bind to stuff that doesn't change. Or use `oneWayBinding` when possible.

Comment: Thanks. I don't believe scheduleOnce will help in this case though - all the updates will still happen in the same loop (same as with next). Unless I am misunderstanding how you would use it? Basically I need to find a way to execute each "doUpdates" in a different loop...